# How can I exclude an object from my model?

Tags: django

I need to exclude 1 size from my model Good with field: `Size = models.ManyToManyField('Size')`

Size model:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length = 15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.size
```

I try do this in views.py:

```
good1 = Good.objects.get(id = good_id)
choosen_good_size = good1.Size.get(size = 'XS')
choosen_good_size.exclude()
good1.save()
```

But I get an error:
Exception Value: 'Size' object has no attribute 'exclude'

In another cases I get AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Good instances

What should I do to make it works?

Comment: So you want to *remove it from the `Size`s of `good1`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [**`.remove(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.remove) for this, like:

```
good1 = Good.objects.get(id=good_id)
size = Size.objects.get(size='XS')

good1.Size.remove(size)
```

> **Note**: according to PEP-8, you probably should name the `ManyToManyField` `sizes`, instead of `Size`.

[**`.exclude(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) is used by `QuerySet`s and `Manager`s to omit certain records that is in the database from a `QuerySet`, the records are still there, but you do not want to retrieve it for some reason.